# Проблема при создании пустого android проекта Android Studio/IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Проблема в следующем:
при создании пустого проекта даже без активити возникают одни и теже ошибки, что в idea и AS.

```
Error:Error: Duplicate resources
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
[style-ldltr-v21/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined]
MyApplication244/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/res/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml
[style-ldltr-v21/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined]
MyApplication244/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/res/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.inoob.myapplication244"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
}
```

build.gradle(MyApplication244)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Пробовал ставить на предыдущие версии API 21, 22, 23
результат такой же
Гугл меня не спас
мб у меня не та версия гугла ) ткните куда смотреть пожалуйста

Comment: покажите файл settings.gradle

Comment: include ':app'
вот и все что там описано

Comment: Вам наверняка не нужны тесты - удалите их и проблема должна исчезнуть

Answer (score 1):

У вас дублирование зависимостей. Скорее всего это вызвано подключенными по умолчанию фреймворками для тестов. Есть два пути. Правильный в вашем случае (тесты вам, думаю, сейчас не нужны) - удалить зависимости с тестами. Т.е. строки:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

---

Либо убрать конкретные модули из зависимости тестов:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
})
```

Comment: попробовал оба варианта. Если собирать проект грейдлом снова вылетают те же ошибки.

Comment: @НиколайМоргунов, первый способ реально не помог? Вы точно всё удалили? А build/clean пробовали?

Comment: да не помог я раз 5 попробовал clean/build

Comment: @НиколайМоргунов, и вы совсем ничего не добавляли и не изменяли в проекте? И перезапуск студии не помогает?

Comment: и перезапуск тоже не помогает , а есть какой-то способ в самом грейдле отключить тесты? я имею ввиду из цикла построения проекта

Comment: @НиколайМоргунов, не думаю что это возможно и даже нужно. Попробуйте ещё SDK потереть и заново закачать - может в этом проблема

Comment: проблему так и не удалось решить скачал др готовый проект там все работает. Буду уже использовать его как заготовку